# How to run run multiple jobs in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have 5 spring batches inside a jar. I have 1 spring dataflow **app** and 1 **task**. To launch a particular job, I am using below command :

```
java -jar jobName=job1 --spring.cloud.task.executionid=10
```

Everytime I launch a task, I have to provide **jobName** parameter. My question is how do I avoid this? Can I create 5 **tasks** (with single jar) corresponding to 5 jobs, so that I can start task1 and job1 is launched?
Basically, how to manage multiple jobs(contained in single jar) in spring dataflow?

Answer (score 0):

Once you combine all the batches into one single jar, then you need a way to control which batch to launch based on some command line arg or a job parameter.

But, to answer your question, yes you can create multiple task definitions using the same task application which has all the batch applications.

For instance, if you have a task application registered as `mytask1` which is the jar file.

Then, you can create multiple task definitions for the same task app:

task-batch1=mytask1
task-batch2=mytask1
..
task-batch5=mytask1

This way, you can launch the batches individually or using composed tasks.

But, you still need a way to launch a specific batch job inside the jar.

Comment: How can I link task-batch1 with job1(spring batch in jar). I know I can provide arguments while launching a task, but can I do this at the time of task creation so that I don't have to provide arguments every time I launch a task?